# iOS React Native: Emit Event from ViewDidAppear to View Component

Tags: react-native-ios

I have a react view as the main view of a native View Controller.  I want my native View Controller to dispatch an event after ViewDidAppear that my react component NativeEventEmitter is listening for.

```
componentDidMount(){
    const eventManager = new NativeEventEmitter(ReactMainManager);

    this._subscription = eventManager.addListener(
       'ViewDidLoad', 
        (info) => {
           //.. do something 
        }
    );
    ...
```

InsideEventEmitter

```
@objc func viewWasHit(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock){
  self.sendEvent(withName: "ViewDidLoad", body: [])
}
```

Inside ReactViewController

```
class subClassReactViewController: ReactViewController{
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
     if let reactView = reactRootView as? RCTRootView{
        //How do I fire viewHasHit from here? 
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended using Notification Center for lack of a better solution.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("InfoViewAppeared"), object: nil)
}
```

In RCTEventEmitter

class ReactAccountInfoManager: RCTEventEmitter{

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ReactAccountInfoManager.viewAppeared), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "InfoViewAppeared"), object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) 
}



@objc func viewAppeared(){

   self.sendEvent(withName: "ViewAppeared", body: headerDictionary)

}
```